# Kickstarter refund via PayPal, scam?

Tags: paypal, scams, crowdfunding

Lately comments on a kickstarter project got strange:
People claim to have received "refund" transfers ranging $0.99-$99 via PayPal, which they didn't request.

PayPal transfers are notably revocable. So a scammer, money launderer or identity thief could
(step 1) "invest" someone's money,
(step 2) ask for a payback of a mistaken refund (most likely via a different/irrevocable payment method) and
(step 3) don't care about the original transfer being revoked/bouncing.

So far no comment has indicated step 2 is happening. It's also unlikely to work for the scammer, because the targeted campaign is considered by many backers to be on its way down the drain: Some backers requested/would be happy to receive a refund.

I suppose, it's a scam. No one said, all scammers are bright.
**However, what would I need to watch out for, if I got a possibly fraudulent "refund" transfer via PayPal?**

**What's the difference, if I have/haven't requested a refund?**

Comment: It's sounding more like incompetence than scam, unless the scam is to refund the money to the wrong people and pocket some if it in the process.

Comment: Well, maybe it's too subtle for me to recognize the actual scam from what **other** people wrote in their comments but yeah, currently it doesn't look like a competent scammer. That's why I'm asking about specifics of PayPal and the difference for "requested" refunds.

Comment: I've received a partial refund for a failed kickstarter via PayPal. But I needed to provide the paypal details and specifically agree that accepting the refund would keep me from pursuing further action in response to the failure.